# No tests found using JMock

Tags: java, ant, junit, jmock

having problems trying to run by unit test with Ant, my test class uses Jmock;

```
@RunWith(JMock.class)
```

and annotations to identify each test method. When i attempt to build with ant (1.7.1) i get a

> [junit] No tests found in MyTestClass 
>   [junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:  No tests found

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show us the whole class? or at least the imports and one method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of JUnit are you using? It looks like 3.8 to me (although I could be mistaken) but the package structure for JUnit 4.x is: `org.junit` and not `junit.framework`

The `@RunWith` runner as defined by the JMock guys is only valid with JUnit 4.x

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JUnit 3, you should inherit from MockObjectTestCase instead of using the Runner